# SQLite: how to exclude records in a database with join tables?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, join, group-by

I have a database with a schema similar to:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS song_artist
(
    song INTEGER, 
    artist INTEGER,

    FOREIGN KEY("song") REFERENCES "Songs"("song_id") 
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY("artist") REFERENCES "Artists"("artist_id") 
        ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Artists 
(
    "artist_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    "artist_name" TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Songs 
(
    "song_id" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    "song_name" TEXT
);
```

Say they have the following data in them:

```sql
INSERT INTO Artists (artist_name) VALUES ("Bob");
INSERT INTO Artists (artist_name) VALUES ("Shawn");

INSERT INTO Songs (song_name) VALUES ("one song");
INSERT INTO Songs (song_name) VALUES ("another song");

INSERT INTO song_artist (artist, song) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT INTO song_artist (artist, song) VALUES (2, 1);
INSERT INTO song_artist (artist, song) VALUES (2, 2);
```

`Artists`:

| artist_id | artist_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Bob |
| 2 | Shawn |

`Songs`:

| song_id | song_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one song |
| 2 | another song |

`song_artist`:

| song | artist |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

Here, both `Bob` and `Shawn` are involved in `one song`, and only `Shawn` is involved in `another song`. Say I wanted to get the names of the songs where `Shawn` is involved, but not `Bob`. So, in this case it would be only `another song`. However, as to be expected, this query doesn't work as it gives me both the songs:

```sql
SELECT song_name
FROM Songs
JOIN Artists ON Artists.artist_id = song_artist.artist
JOIN song_artist ON song_artist.song = Songs.song_id
WHERE Artists.artist_name = "Shawn"
  AND Artists.artist_name != "Bob"
```

|  | song_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | one song |
| 2 | another song |

This would be the result of the join table `song_artist` having multiple records for the same song, so even if a record with `Bob`'s ID is excluded, there's still another record without `Bob`'s ID that gets included in the final result.

Here's how I've found a workaround to this:

```sql
SELECT song_name
FROM Songs
JOIN Artists ON Artists.artist_id = song_artist.artist
JOIN song_artist ON song_artist.song = Songs.song_id
WHERE Artists.artist_name = "Shawn"
  AND Songs.song_id NOT IN (SELECT song_id
                            FROM Songs
                            JOIN Artists ON Artists.artist_id = song_artist.artist
                            JOIN song_artist ON song_artist.song = Songs.song_id
                            WHERE Artists.artist_name == "Bob")
```

|  | song_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | another song |

Now, while this works as expected, as one can imagine, this becomes a long winded query once you have a lot more than a single join table. I also assume this is a very un-optimized query. My question is, what is a better way to do this kind of query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add a `WHERE` clause in your query which filters out any other artists than Shawn and Bob.
Then use conditional aggregation and in the `HAVING` clause add the condition that Bob does not participate in the song (which leaves only Shawn):

```
SELECT s.*
FROM Songs s
JOIN song_artist sa ON sa.song = s.song_id
JOIN Artists a ON a.artist_id = sa.artist
WHERE a.artist_name IN ('Shawn', 'Bob')
GROUP BY s.song_id
HAVING SUM(a.artist_name = 'Bob') = 0;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=3286e310ada76a76a2123121fa7f6367).

Comment: I apologize if it wasn't clear in the OP, but I don't want songs that only have `Shawn` in them, I want songs that have `Shawn` along with whoever else, except for `Bob`. So, a song featuring only `Shawn` and `John` would also be selected. See my comment to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73265916/19610681

Comment: @London my query excludes only Bob. Any other artist  is allowed

Comment: Maybe kill the `WHERE` clause, but otherwise this answer looks correct to me.

Comment: Oh, you're right. My bad.

Comment: @London check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=67875b3d3f6ee695050231c2394e994e

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS'`to exclude Bob

> ```
> SELECT song_name
> FROM Songs s
> JOIN song_artist sa ON sa.song = s.song_id
> JOIN Artists a ON a.artist_id = sa.artist
> WHERE a.artist_name = 'Shawn'
>   AND NOT EXiSTS(SELECT 1 FROM song_artist 
>   WHERE artist = (SELECT artist_id FROM Artists WHERE  Artists.artist_name = 'Bob') 
> AND song = sa.song
> )
> ```
>
> ```
> song_name
> another song
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.39&fiddle=704d41acc3061b8c1b4a485b0c3086da)*

Answer (score 0):

An exists query might be more effective in large sets and is more readable than aggregation tricks IMHO:

```
select * from Songs s
where 
exists (select * from Song_Artist sa inner join
   artists a on sa.artist = a.artist_id
   where s.song_id = sa.song and a.artist_Name = 'Shawn')
and   
not exists (select * from Song_Artist sa inner join
   artists a on sa.artist = a.artist_id
   where s.song_id = sa.song and a.artist_Name = 'Bob');
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=e4d4ab2a393f305c624ec8e43b539f1c)